# "Protective armor" Why does such a word combination exist?

Tags: american-english, british-english, pleonasms

Why does such a word combination as "Protective armor" exist? Is there non-protective armor?

Please, explain if there is some nuance.

Comment: The term seems strangely redundant. The redundancy is not generally noticed by readers as it just tells the reader what the writer want to emphasis about the armor. In fact there is ceremonial armor, not for fighting but for looking good long after a fight, though this is just a more attractive version, no less protective.

Comment: I see, thank you!

Comment: I suspect that ceremonial armour would be far thinner and lighter.

Comment: There is also firepower armor and manpower armor. They meet at the armory.